# Why do we insist that the electron be a point particle when calculation shows it creates an electrostatic field of infinite energy?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, elementary-particles, point-particles, self-energy

I've heard [compelling reasons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234979/) to think that it is one although why do we assert this in light of the calculation which shows a point particle creates an electrostatic field of infinite energy (see e.g. Griffiths ED 2.4.4 or Feynman Lectures vol. 2 section 28)?

Why do people not consider this calculation a definitive reason to abandon the notion that the electron is a point particle?

Comment: Your mathematical expression is malformed ($r$ only appears in the limit, but not in the symbols that follow), and it's not clear what relationship that has to whether an electron is a point particle.

Comment: In modern physics an electron is a quantum. Quanta are not objects but amounts of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges (electric charge but also other quantum numbers like lepton number). There are, unfortunately, a lot of really poor explanations in circulation, both among lay people and physicists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The problem of infinite energy of electron as point charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386760/)

Comment: @FlatterMann But quanta can be arbitrarily localized in space (constructing wavepackets) and the distinction between a quantum and point particle can be made indiscernible (as far as I can tell). My question would then be rephrased as "Can an electron 'quantum' be localized to arbitrary spatial extent?" In which case the quantum can be localized and via the $\int \vec{E}^2dV$ calculation, it can be constructed to produce E fields of arbitrarily large energy...

Comment: You seem to have a factual misconception. Namely, that an electron 'is a point particle'. According to modern knowledge, it's not; that's just not how quantum field theory (or even quantum mechanics) works. Also, if you allow a point particle, aren't you worried about the gravitational singularity, too?

Comment: @greatscissors - Suppose that quanta can be arbitrarily localised in space. (It is not clear that this is the case; we have not made GR compatible with QFT and we don't know whether space is discretised). This is not the same thing as saying a particle can be localised to a *single point*. Analagous to how there are arbitrarily large integers, there is no such thing as the '$\infty$' integer. (There are extended number systems etc but I'll not get bogged down into details.)

Comment: @greatscissors 
You may be confused/misled on this matter because dirac-delta distributions are used a lot in physics. There are many times when they are good for intuition, and in which the operations end up well-defined. Dirac-delta distributions are very useful in that sense. However, the concept is not well-defined-- for some purposes it is, and in those cases we use them, but it's not always well-defined.

For example, a Dirac-delta distribution can be expressed as a limiting sequence of well-defined distributions. The particular sequence you use changes the outcome of some calculation

Comment: @greatscissors the particular choice of sequence is related to the 'regularisation' of a quantum field theory. This is a rather deep technical matter which is woefully under-appreciated. Uncountably-infinite-dimensional vector spaces are quite different beasts. Concepts/definitions which are well-defined for lower dimensional spaces are no longer well-defined.

Comment: @Myridium What localizes an electron in an experiment is always a piece of matter. We can, of course, make statements about the minimal spatial cutoff that we need to explain scattering between electrons or electrons and photons and we know that there is no internal structure in any of the experiments we have done, so far. But there is a difference between field interactions without a spatial scale and a "point particle".   It is esoteric for most applications, which is why most physicists don't (have to) care about it. Those who do often seem to end up on the wrong side of the issue, though.

Comment: @Myridium If it's not a point particle, in what sense do people mean it is one when asserting that it is in QFT (e.g. the response from Anna V in link provided in original question)?

Comment: @FlatterMann the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is hardly an esoteric matter. I'm not talking of some kind of pedantry; this is an integral part of QFT and QM we're talking about. The fact that particles aren't point-like is kind of the historical foundation of quantum mechanics. So not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @greatscissors - 2 points. 1) In that response, anna v says "this probability might be constrained on a point, *if the dimensions are macroscopic*". It mean the particle is tightly localised in space. Not to a single point, but it looks like that when you zoom out far enough. That's why electrons appear point-like at our human scale. And 2) it is computationally convenient, in many instances, to decompose a field into a linear combination of Dirac-delta functions. As I mentioned above, it's convenient and intuitive, and frequently aids calculations. It's a computational technique.

Comment: @Myridium The uncertainty relation is a fairly trivial mathematical lemma about linear operators. It shows up in basically every theory that has linear waves in it and uses concepts like the Fourier transformation. What is non-trivial, is that quanta come as either fermions of bosons, which is a dimension dependent symmetry that does not exist in the classical mean field theory. That is why quantum mechanics can explain matter and classical fields can't. Don't get me wrong: what I am simply getting at is that we need to stop talking about "particles" altogether. It's an educational issue.

Comment: @Myridium AH, I overlooked that in her statement actually! Thank you for your help I really think you and many in here have straightened this out for me. 

To summarize, it's not a point particle---it's rather a *quantum* capable of very narrow localization (yes, by a piece of matter---e.g. geonium in one of the most extreme case). More often than not it can be considered a "point particle" although we always keep in mind that this is just an approximate description sufficient in most circumstances.

Comment: @greatscissors - exactly :) If you have two 'point' charges which you suppose are very small gaussians, the energy of the EM field will be not infinite but very large. A constant added to the energy, no matter how large, has no effect. Energy is arbitrary up to adding a constant. Due to Gauss' law and spherical symmetry, as long as the 'gaussians' don't overlap, then they are approx point-particles in the way they interact. However, as the charges get close together, you can imagine that the approximation breaks down. Once they overlap, the details matter. Rough classical intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do people not consider this calculation a definitive reason to abandon the notion that the electron is a point particle?

Because that calculation is based on a dubious assumption that energy associated with point charged particle is given by the standard formula for Coulomb energy of a sphere, or extended charged object with spherical symmetry. When we try radius consistent with experiments on electrons ($r<$1e-18 m), we get energy higher than rest energy of the electron. Thus the Coulomb interaction energy formula is extrapolated somewhere where it clearly does not work well.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This discussion went a bit off-topic from what I was originally looking for but this is really the sort of reasoning I was after.

Answer (score 10):

> Why do we insist that the electron be a point particle [...]?

We do not. For example, [measurements of the electron](https://www.nature.com/articles/news.2011.321) validate that it's charge distribution has *spherical* symmetry to within an error of $10^{-15}$. And point can't have any geometrical symmetries, hence electron is not a point particle.

Point particle approximations are used in some models for useful first order insights.

It's like when you analyze the Sun's trajectory in our galaxy: you can imagine the Sun being a "point particle", because
${d_\odot}/{r} \approx 10^{-12}\ll 1$, where $r$ is our distance to Milky Way galaxy center (about $24~\textrm{kly}$). Hence, the Sun's diameter can be ignored in these types of problems. However, in other types of problems it is important, like evaluating black body radiation, measuring the exact barycenter of solar system rotation etc.

It is the same for particles: if the model at hand doesn't require exact shape of particle, it doesn't use it.

Comment: The news page you cite in fact states that the electron is a sphere. The articles cited by that news page, as far as I understand, only state that the eletron's charge is spherically symmetric. Seems to be a strange simplification (nature-style). https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.071805 and https://doi.org/10.1038/nature10104

Comment: @reciprocallettuce - in essence, those groups are probing for indications that the electron is a composite, not an elemental, particle.

Comment: @reciprocallettuce In fact if to be precise,- mentioned researches measures electron electric dipole moment. If it has some, then electric fields should change electron spin orientation even a bit. And the fact that they have found none, shows that electron's negative charge is distributed spherically without any "hills" or "pits". This is equivalent of saying that shape of electron is an "ideal" sphere. I don't see the difference between the two. What you say - is more "a word play".

Comment: @JonCuster As for me, I think you are making too-far reaching conclusions. Does standard model forbid elementary particles (non-composite) which are not symmetrical ? I haven't heard about such limitations. But you may be right that it _would be good_ to expect symmetry on elementary particles. Though, science history has shown to us multiple times that not everything what we expect becomes true.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas - Perhaps I overstated. However, to quote doi:10.1038/nature10104 (JJ Hudson et al.): "However, many extensions to the standard
model naturally predict much larger values of de that should be
detectable3. This makes the search for the electron EDM a powerful
way to search for new physics and constrain the possible extensions.
In particular, the popular idea that new supersymmetric
particles may exist at masses of a few hundred GeV/c2 (where c is
the speed of light) is difficult to reconcile with the absence of an
electron EDM at the present limit of sensitivity."

Comment: But doesn't the assumption of the particle being a ball not also give a singularity at the boundary of that ball? So this does not answer the question.

Comment: @JannikPitt - A ball of charge would not give a singularity at the surface.  Consider a day-to-day spherically distributed charge.  To avoid worries about what happens inside a charged sphere, distribute the charge evenly along the surface.  Electric field at the surface is proportional to the charge density on the surface, not infinity.

Comment: @JannikPitt I think invoking images of a (solid) sphere, let alone a "ball" mentally misleads us. The "reality" at this scale has nothing to do with a typical textbook drawing. It is not even a "reality" as one would commonly understand the term (i.e. something unambiguous with a certain stability).

Comment: The difference between an object exhibiting spherical symmetry and an actual sphere is much more than just "word play". The atmosphere of the earth, for example, exhibits spherical symmetry (to a certain approximation), but it is not an actual sphere. Even better, the electric field generated by a point charge (such as an electron) exhibits spherical symmetry, but it is not an actual sphere.

Comment: @LeeMosher _The atmosphere of the earth, for example, exhibits spherical symmetry (to a certain approximation)_. Then it **IS** a sphere (to a certain approximation).

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas that's like saying a face with perfect reflection symmetry “is a mirror”. Being a sphere means not just having a spherical symmetry; it means (both in maths and common speech) something has a finite extend and a sharply defined boundary at a given radius. Or, well, mathematically the sphere _is_ that boundary. Some mathematicians might even say a sphere is anything that's homeomorphic to $S^2$, including things that are _not_ spherically symmetric. So, no, saying the electron “is a sphere” is not good, it neither expresses the symmetry nor possible non-sharpness etc..

Comment: @leftaroundabout _mathematically the sphere is that boundary_. I don't see any problems of sphere boundary being fuzzy. For example, many viruses have spherical shape, but it's boundary neither continuous, nor perfect ($\sigma_r \gt 0$). So, as for me, I understand term "sphere" in more broad sense,- it doesn't have to have a clear boundary, with exact $R$. We may just have approximate $\overline R \pm \Delta R$.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas a spherical virus still has $\sigma_r < r$, if not $\sigma_r \ll r$. So it's at least approximately sharp-delimited. Similar for the Earth surface or even its atmosphere, but very much not for the electron.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Still you don't give a reason why sphere couldn't be non-sharp delimited, but for example gradient-like. If you would draw radial gradient in any drawing program like Gimp or Photoshop, you would see that it's a circular even when circle inner black color gradually changes into paper background white color. So you can say that radial gradient "blob" finally becomes as paper part. But still you can visually see borders of circle. I think same applies for electron,- we can determine it's size and sequentially,- sphere shape, event it's "blurry". Sphere doesn't have to be sharp.

Comment: The reason that it can't be non-sharp delimited is simply that this is not what a sphere is – it's a matter of definition, and yours is wrong (or nonstandard if you prefer). A sphere has/is a surface that is a submanifold, i.e. the extent in normal direction is vanishing or at least substantially smaller than the extent in the tangential directions. A radial gradient doesn't have that property. Of course it has _level sets_ that have the property, but that's a different story.

Comment: Yes, I agree that my view is non-standard. But..., I'll ask you,- if electron has finite volume and it's shape is not sphere-like, then What shape it has ? I understand that sphere may be not the best analogy to describe how electron looks like, but I think we don't have better comparisons so far and certainly it's not "a point-like particle", so... And yes, I was having in mind level-sets in a radial gradient describing analogies with blurry electron boundaries. Again, I did not find better analogies to picture it in "usual world". If you'll find them,- you are more than welcome to say them.

Answer (score 5):

> why do we assert this in light of the calculation which shows a point particle creates an electrostatic field of infinite energy

Actually this is one of the reasons quantum mechanics had to be invented. If there were a singularity at the center of charged particles then  when they were attracted to each other they would fall and neutralize so no atoms and molecules as we have measured them would exist, or us either. [Bohr with his model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html) tried to solve this by using a planetary model for bound states that has a quantized angular momentum. This eventually led to the theory of quantum mechanics and its [postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) where rigorous mathematics can be used to calculate and predict the behavior of particles in the phase space region where classical electrodynamics would predict singularities.

The wave function postulate is important in this, second page in the link. The wave nature of the solution for interactions between particles, controls their behavior in interactions. Only the probability distributions of a particle being at (x,y,z,t) with four vector $(p_x,p_y,p_z,E)$ can be calculated.

See [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744211/does-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-allow-for-retroactive-calculation-of-both/744238#744238) to get a feeling about the probability build up of the wave nature.

Comment: But quantum mechanics doesn't resolve the calculation. Quantum mechanics includes the 1/r Coulomb singularity in the H atom and gets quantization in spite of it. Meanwhile, a free electron can still be constructed to have arbitrarily large electrostatic energy via wavepackets.

Comment: @greatscissors you can do anything with mathematics , The point is to fit the data, and QFT fits the data and is predictive. The 1/r in the quantum mechanical equation defines the wavefunction solutions, the probabilities, not the location of the particle.

Comment: @greatscissors Unless I've misunderstood your meaning, the fact that an electron gets arbitrarily large energy (expectation value) when it is arbitrarily localized has nothing to do with electrostatic energy. The same would happen to a neutron (even though it has a radius unlike the electron!)

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the question. The reason for introducing "quantum" in the "pre-Bohr classical planetary model of the atom" is that the accelerated charge moving around looses energy through radiation. You don't need the singularity of the electric potential for that, just replace it by $\frac{1}{r+\varepsilon}$, $\varepsilon>0$, and the argument by Bohr should still work, right?

Comment: @kricheli but not the same spectral  series will be predicted y a different potential. The model fitted the data

Comment: Of course. But if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small or you have an electron form factor with a sufficiently small radius, you don't see the difference/the data fits as well. But the singularity is gone.

Comment: @kricheli That the singularity is gone is not just a matter of cutoff IMHO. It's a matter of dynamics. While it is easy to imagine that we can bring two point charges together as close as we want, in reality that process would, even in classical theory, cause a strong spike in dipole radiation, which carries energy away from the system, in other words, we can't actually measure the classical binding energy in a unique way. In the quantum mechanical version the localization by an external force causes a non-Coulomb energy term, so the "naked" charge problem is ill-defined to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

When we write down the equations of the Standard Model of Elementary particles, the electron appears as a field that is represented as an irreducible representation of the Lorentz group, the Dirac spinor.  This is an object which has no substructure.  Note that this is subtly different from a point particle, in that this is not a statement about a spatial extent.  Instead, it is a statement about the field's response to Lorentz transformations (or more generally, Poincaré transformations, this includes rotations and changes in uniform velocity).

In particular, the fields are arranged in such a way that the equations of motions stay independent of a choice of inertial frame (technically, the Lagrangian is invariant under Lorentz transformations, for the free Dirac field this looks like $\mathcal{L}_\textrm{free} = \bar \psi ( i \hbar c \partial\llap{\unicode{x2215}} - m_ec^2) \psi$).  This is something that in a classical setting cannot be done for an extended object.  This is easy to understand if you are familiar with Lorentz contraction: e.g. a sphere will become an ellipsoid in any frame where it is moving, and thus the rotational symmetry is broken.  So in classical theory, only a point-like object can be Lorentz-invariant.  I believe this is why we call objects without substructure, i.e. those that transform according to irreducible representations, "point-like".

My [old answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458587/in-particle-colliders-according-to-qm-how-are-two-particles-able-to-collide/458625#458625) gives some insight into how the spatial "size" of such an object can be usefully defined (a radius would be the square root of the cross-sections mentioned there give or take a factor $\pi$).  Now, the only reaction-independent length scale you can construct in a theory of only electrons and photons is $\frac{e^2}{m_ec^2} \approx 10^{-15}\textrm{m}$ which is known as the classical electron radius.  Why is it the only one?  Because there are only two inputs characterizing the theory: the electron charge $e$ and the electron mass $m_e$, and this is the only combination that has dimensions of a length.  Since this is the only length scale, it is bound to appear all over the cross-sections related to electron scattering, and in that sense it can usefully be considered a measure of the size of the electron.  Let me emphasize though that the actual cross-section in any reaction will also depend on the other available length scales in the reaction (derived from masses of other particles, center-of-mass energies, energy transfers ...), so one shouldn't think of the classical electron radius as "the" size of the electron.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow me to paraphrase: You are making the case that since the energy of a Coulomb electric field is infinite at the origin, the electron must not really be a point particle. First I will summarize some evidence in favor of point-like particles, without coming to a final conclusion. Then I will address the Coulomb potential and our ability to make a conclusion from that infinity.

On the former: Well, really every experiment that has been done shows particle-like nature on each individual run. Let me give you some example for context.

Check out this image of the trajectory of an electron from a cloud chamber:
[image]

In addition, in a screen-like setup like a multi-channel plate, which is basically a bunch of cavities that an electron can enter, we only ever get a signal in one channel at once.

What else? Consider the Milikan's oil drop experiment. There's a good video of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HhaQtvICe8). The charge of the electron was found in this experiment, and every charge seen in the experiment is a multiple of that base charge. That suggests a final granularity of electrons.

There are pretty much endless other examples.

However, as we know, there *is* a wave nature of the electron as well. This wave-particle "duality" has confused mankind for more than 100 years and we still don't have it all quite cleanly sorted out today. Thus many of the arguments around measurement in Quantum Mechanics.

Finally I would like to add that while some experiments are suggestive of pointlike particles, this does not have to be the final say in nature. I show these experiments only to present some relevant evidence that can be weighed in.

> So, how are these compatible with the infinite energy of a Coulomb potential?

The infinite energy of a Coulomb potential is an issue for sure. But we already know that our electrodynamics is not the final story, so an issue there is likely just indication of the limitations of our theory. Quantum Electrodynamics is a more fundamental theory, however even here the singularity still causes issues. We are able to tame these issues with a process called renormalization.

But regardless of whether one considers this an issue in QED... even QED is not the end of the story. Since we don't have a final theory, we don't know what an electron actually IS. So we can't rule out the possibility that there is a way for it to have a point-like nature while still having a total energy that doesn't cause our theories to blow up. The way of calculating energy (if there even is one in a hypothetical final theory) may be completely different than $\int\vec{E}^2 dV$. As such, we have no way of ruling out a pointlike nature of the electron.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145329/discussion-on-answer-by-doublefelix-why-do-we-insist-that-the-electron-be-a-poin); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting point. I’ve had similar problems with the origins and properties of the electron. And they also indicate that the concept of the electron as a point particle with only neg charge should be questioned.
My research shows that in 1897 Zeeman noticed spectral splitting of atomic emission lines.Lorentz explained this as proof of existence of the electron as a point particle ,proof of Lorentz force and validation of his model of electromagnetism. Yet in fact in his theory, his ion ( That’s what he called the electron initially) emits polarised radiation perpendicular to its plane of Rotation. Clearly violating all observations of induction and emission of emr up till that point. ( emr waves can only be emitted parallel to the rotation plane of a dipole). What seems to happen is Lorentz, ignored all empirical observation current to 1897 and erroneously assumes his ion /electron is a point particle with a neg charge. So my answer to,your question is Yes, people should abandon this concept of the electron as a point particle. And the reason is that its properties contradict all known observations of emr.